# Override the arity of a function

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a generic function wrapper that (for example) prints the called function and its arguments.

Doing so is easy through the `arguments` quasi-array and simple calls. For example:

```
function wrap(target, method) {
    return function() {
        console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', '));
        return method.apply(target, arguments);
    }
}
```

However, this way of doing of course completely loses the arity of the called function (if you didn't know, one can obtain the arity (number of arguments) of a JavaScript function through its `length` property).

Is there any way to dynamically create a wrapper function that would copy the arguments of the wrapped function to itself?

---

I've thought about creating a new [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), but I don't see any way to statically extract the arguments list, since the [`arguments` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) is deprecated.

Comment: Is there a *real* reason *why* you need to keep `.length` working? I would just use what you've got and forget about `.length.`

Comment: @Matt Yes there is, otherwise I simply wouldn't ask the question… Do you really need me to add all these details?

Comment: I was just checking you weren't so intent on *perfectly* replicating the signature of the function, you hadn't realised it wasn't actually necessary. In all my years of programming JavaScript, I've never had to know the # of named arguments to a function at run time.

Comment: @Matt I need [these methods](https://github.com/MattiSG/Watai/blob/master/src/model/Widget.js#L37-43) to log when they are called, and I need their length [here](https://github.com/MattiSG/Watai/blob/wrap-selenium-failures/src/model/Feature.js#L63-69) to extract all needed arguments from a definition array that linearly lists both closures and their future arguments (example [here](https://github.com/MattiSG/Watai/blob/wrap-selenium-failures/example/DuckDuckGo/1%20-%20ZeroClickFeature.js#L5))  :)

Comment: Are you open to horribly ugly solutions?

Comment: @user1689607 Well, they can always be offered. I guess you're on for rewriting `wrapped.toString()` and `eval`uating it after? I indeed would have preferred to stay away from this  ;)

Comment: How about instead of passing a function multiple parameters, you pass it just one?  An object.  That object's keys can be the "named" parameters you want.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it sounds messy and there's got to be a better solution.

Comment: Today I learned a new word: "Arity" :-)

Comment: Why does it matter how many arguments the function takes?  If you pass it more than it does, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `Function`:

```
// could also generate arg0, arg1, arg2, ... or use the same name for each arg
var argNames = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var makeArgs = function(n) { return [].slice.call(argNames, 0, n).join(','); };

function wrap(target, method) {
    // We can't have a closure, so we shove all our data in one object
    var data = {
        method: method,
        target: target
    }

    // Build our function with the generated arg list, using `this.`
    // to access "closures"
    f = new Function(makeArgs(method.length),
        "console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', '));" +
        "return this.method.apply(this.target, arguments);"
    );
    // and bind `this` to refer to `data` within the function
    return f.bind(data);
}
```

#### EDIT:

Here's a more abstract solution, which fixes the closure problem:

```
function giveArity(f, n) {
    return new Function(makeArgs(n),
        "return this.apply(null, arguments);"
    ).bind(f);
}
```

And a better one, that preserves context when invoked:

```
function giveArity(f, n) {
    return eval('(function('+makeArgs(n)+') { return f.apply(this, arguments); })')
}
```

Used as:

```
function wrap(target, method) {
    return giveArity(function() {
        console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(', '));
        return method.apply(target, arguments);
    }, method.length)
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work: you're losing the actual names of the arguments, and the wrapped function won't work.

Comment: @MattiSG: Why do you need the argument names? There's no way of getting them in code anyway, is there?

Comment: You're right, sorry: the names of the arguments are not needed at this level. [Here](https://gist.github.com/4032135) is a “cleaned-up” version of your solution. That underlines an additional condition, though: the "preflight" part (injected code, `console.log` in your answer) has to get access to some locals… As you said, we have no access to the usual closure magic. I guess the best (only?) solution is to pass an additional parameter, a list of locals to inject into the new function.

Comment: I [ended up](https://gist.github.com/4032135) simply using `giveArity`. Thanks!  :)

Comment: @MattiSG: Note that the second variant of `giveArity` using `eval` lets you rebind `this` at a later stage: `giveArity(function() { console.log(this); }).call("testing")` works with only the second variant.